# Jquery not appending options to select field from array

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a select box and i am using ajax to append options to it. I first want to delete all existing options and append the new options from an array. However The options are not showing.

My select box:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="open_po_number" name="open_po_number" data-style="btn-primary">
    </select>
</div>
```

My ajax response:

```
var vendor_po_list = response.vendor_po_list;
alert(vendor_po_list);
$('#open_po_number').find('option').remove();
$.each(vendor_po_list, function(i, item){
    $('#open_po_number').append($('<option>', {
        value: vendor_po_list[i],
        text: vendor_po_list[i]
    }));
});
```

I am able to see my array in alert box but the values are not appending to the select box. how to do this?
Also i want to delete existing options first.

EDIT:
    // From console log

```
vendor_po_list = ["PO-2", "PO-3", "PO-4", "PO-5", "PO-6", "PO-7", "PO-10", "PO-11"]
```

Complete ajax:

```
$('[name="grn_vendor"]').on('change',function(){
    var vndor_name = $(this).val();
    if (vndor_name != 'none'){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/grn_qc/",
            type : "POST",
            data : {action:'get_po_no',
                    vndor_name:vndor_name},

            success : function(response){
                var vendor_po_list = response.vendor_po_list;
                console.log(vendor_po_list);
                $('#open_po_number').empty();
                $.each(vendor_po_list, function(i, item) {
                  $('#open_po_number').append($('<option>', {
                    value: vendor_po_list[i],
                    text: vendor_po_list[i]
                  }));
                });
            },

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
           });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try appending `item` as in `value: item,
        text: item`

Comment: Also, try adding `vendor_po_list` values in question to get clarification..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It did not work with item too..

Comment: Can you post your complete `ajax` code here?

Comment: Does it matter Since ajax is working fine and the ajax run on when a different element is changed.

Comment: Hopefully that's needed because its good to know where you have place this code inside `ajax`.. I hope inside `success`

Comment: Yes @GuruprasadRao .

Comment: Try one thing.. place a `debugger` after `var vendor_po_list = response.vendor_po_list;` and try executing your `$.each` statement in `console` without moving the `deubbger` and check if you can add there.. Basically @Jai's answer should work.. not sure what is the issue that's stopping here..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Can you tell me how to do that? I am a beginner at jquery.

Comment: write `deubugger` after `var vendor_po_list = response.vendor_po_list;` and open your `console` and execute ajax request.. You will be stopped after successful request and then go to `console`  and execute `$.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use `.empty()` method:

```js
var vendor_po_list = ["PO-2", "PO-3", "PO-4", "PO-5", "PO-6", "PO-7", "PO-10", "PO-11"];

$('#open_po_number').empty();
$.each(vendor_po_list, function(i, item) {
  $('#open_po_number').append($('<option>', {
    value: vendor_po_list[i],
    text: vendor_po_list[i]
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="open_po_number">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that is array or object?

Comment: @ManishGupta See it is working, may be some error is not letting it run. can you update on your browser console? do you see any error there?